# Cannot reach ssh / autossh from outside the remote server

Tags: debian, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a problem with my autossh setup:

- An OpenWRT router has <s>autossh</s> sshtunnel configured to connect to an OVH server I have and setup a remote port on 5922:

  `openWrt$ ssh -R *:5922:localhost:22 user@my_ovh_server`

[image]

- I can see the port opened on the OVH server and can connect on it from within the OVH server:

  `ovh$ ssh localhost -p 5922 -l gui13 # works!`
- I **cannot** connect on that port from outside the OVH server:

  `MyOwnOPC$ ssh my_ovh_server_ip -p 5922 -l gui13 # timeout :/`

Now, [I know about the ssh `GatewayPort`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50064/reverse-port-tunnelling) and it is enabled on the OVH server.

From the OVH server I can see that the port is listening on "*":

[image]

But there's no deal if I try to connect on the public IP of the OVH server.

I can't see anything suspect on the IPTables (fail2bans matches but otherwise no self rules, and standard ports are already reachable).

Here is the sshd config:

```
PermitRootLogin no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
 
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Any idea on how to proceed to find the problem?

Comment: `MyOwnOPC$ ssh my_ovh_server_ip -p 5922 -l gui13`. No user is specified, meaning it is going to use your current local user with which you are logged in `MyOwnOPC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access it from outside you need the reverse tunnel to be open for outbound connections:

```
ssh -R *:5922:localhost:22 user@my_ovh_server
```

If I remember well.. the user used to connect to openwrt routers is `root` by default. That’s the user you'll need when connecting from outside:

```
ssh root@my_ovh_server_ip -p 5922 ...
```

as an improvement to keep the reverse tunnel perpetually alive: I would encourage you to use `autossh` for that purpose.

Comment: Isn't the * the default value? From [https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh](`man ssh`): An empty bind_address, or the address '*', indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Nope, I think you got confused: `ssh -R *:5922:localhost:22 user@my_ovh_server` means the same as `ssh -R :5922:localhost:22 user@my_ovh_server`. Meaning that `:` (an empty bind address) is equivalent to `*:`, but you will need to add it to get all interfaces to listen, otherwise it won't work. Without that it will only listen to localhost (`my_ovh_server`), which is exactly what you described in your post. Hope this helps further to clear out any confusion.

Comment: So, it actually *is* `*:5922:localhost:22`, not "nothing:5922". This is what is making me pull my hairs!

Comment: Is it still not working? Have you checked the firewall in the ovh server? Using ufw? The port 5922 needs to be open.

Comment: No `ufw` on the OVH side. `iptables` returns only fail2ban chains. sshd seems configured OK, I activated `GatewayPorts`. I expose some non-standard ports already on the server (8086 for influxdb) and they work fine! I don't understand the problem. And now I broke the reverse SSH tunnel so I'll have to get back to the place to fix it. Thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: @Gui13 can you update your question with additional vital information, like the sshd_config...?

Comment: Here it is! Marc I appreciate your help !

Comment: `sshd_config` looks ok for the server (the most important part is `GatewayPorts yes`, which means that by default anyone can connect to the forwarded ports. If the server is on the public Internet, anyone on the Internet can connect to the port. With this setting, there is no need to add `*:` or `:` as we discussed previously). What about the openwrt router? What is the user you use to connect to it? If I remember well.. it is `root` for openwrt routers. That’s the user you'll need when connecting from outside, meaning: `ssh root@my_ovh_server_ip -p 5922 -v`.

Comment: By the way, as an improvement to keep the reverse tunnel perpetually alive: I would encourage you to use `autossh` for that purpose.

Comment: Yep I use sshtunnel (uses the actual ssh, not the dropbear exe). The issue is still here, I can see from a tcpdump that the packets arrive to the OVH server, they are sent through to the OWRT router, but then they are not returned. There's something strange..

Comment: That was clear. Can you share the ssh config in your owrt router?

Comment: Ok, I have the answer. `ufw` was here. It required sudo rights and I must have not used sudo. I just added the port and all is now fine... My bad